# Select Query on PGSql Does not return Data. While running query manual does give 2 columns C#

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am trying to retrieve data from the One Table with Parameters. But While Running below code does not give any Rows. But While I Run query manually It does give me output.

```
// Create SQL command
var cmdSelectMain = new NpgsqlCommand(sqlQuerySql, connectionDB);
cmdSelectMain.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@SystemId", getJsonObject["StackName"].ToString()));
cmdSelectMain.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@UserName", getJsonObject["UserName"].ToString()));
cmdSelectMain.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@Name", getPatchObject["PatchString"].ToString()));
    
if (Startup.ConfigurationProvider.TestSettings.Debug)
{
testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Query Printing -> " + sqlQuerySql.Replace("@SystemId", getJsonObject["StackName"].ToString()).Replace("@UserName", getJsonObject["UserName"].ToString()).Replace("@Name", getPatchObject["PatchString"].ToString()));
                            }
    
using (var npgsqlDataReader = cmdSelectMain.ExecuteReader())
{
if (npgsqlDataReader.HasRows)
{
//testOutputHelper.WriteLine("PatchID: {0}, SystemId:{1}, IsLocationGroupSpecific:{2} ,IsActive:{3} ", npgsqlDataReader.GetInt32(0), npgsqlDataReader.GetString(1), npgsqlDataReader.GetBoolean(2), npgsqlDataReader.GetBoolean(3));
npgsqlDataReader.Read();
testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Patch ID -> " + (int)npgsqlDataReader["PatchId"]);
testOutputHelper.WriteLine("System ID -> " + (String)npgsqlDataReader["SystemId"]);
testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Location Specific ID -> " + (Boolean)npgsqlDataReader["IsLocationGroupSpecific"]);
testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Active ID -> " + (Boolean)npgsqlDataReader["IsActive"]);
setofString = (int)npgsqlDataReader["PatchId"] + ",";
}
else
{
testOutputHelper.WriteLine("Reader Does not has Rows Something Went Wrong");
}
}
```

I am getting the Data when Query I execute manually query does prints properly.

Any help and suggestion will be welcomed.

Thanks you.
Kishan

Comment: Please don't post with wads of leading whitespace and force us to scroll horizontally to read it. You can hold down the Alt key while selecting text in VS to select an arbitrary block, so there's no need to select all that leading whitespace. If you are going to do so though, don't chop it off the first line and not the rest, because then you could use the SO editor to remove all the whitespace. Be considerate and make the effort to make your code as readable as possible.

Comment: As for the question, if you execute the same query against the same database with the same permissions then you'll get the same results. That's it, that's all. If you're not getting the same results then at least one of those things is different. We can't see any of them so we can't really tell you what's different.

Comment: Yes query Does give me results and Yeah the same user name and password I am logging in with. It as error or something I would never post question.